# Download a PHP generated CSV/PDF using mysql

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, download

I have a form that generates an SQL statement, based on the users choices.  It is functioning much like the report wizard in MS Access.  On the last step, I have all the data, and the dynamically generated SQL query, but I need a way where they can download it as a file.  How should I go about this?

Currently I have three buttons called 
'View Results' (which just shows HTML generated results, that is easy - they just open up in a new tab)

'Download CSV' (preferably I would like this when clicked to just act like a normal download of a file, the user gets prompted to save as etc by the browser)

'Download PDF' (same as CSV)

At the moment when the CSV button is pressed a new tab opens up with export_report.php, 
which outputs CSV style report data.

How can I achieve the desired results with the CSV and PDF button?  I have all the data and information I need to generate either but I am unsure how to proceed forward with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the generation of the PDF you could use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) witch allows you to build a pdf from php.

For the generation of the CSV you only have to adjust the headers. Here is a link that explains how this works: [csv generation](http://www.askageek.com/2006/02/28/generate-a-csv-file-using-php/).